# Magento 2: Order Success Page Not Loading for custom payment method

Tags: magento-2.1, redirect, order-success-page

I am using Webkul Ccavenue extension for **Magento 2.1.4**. On successful payment, a success response is sent to Magento, after which it should redirect to order success page(`checkout/onepage/success`), but it redirects to cart page, while the order gets successfully placed.

Any help would be appreciated.